# source a script from gdb

Tags: shell, gdb

Before I debug or execute a program on my system at work, I have to source a file that contains numerous paths and settings that are specific to each project. Is there a way I can do this from gdb? I tried putting it into a .gdbinit file in the working directory, but that doesn't seem to be working. I tried to see if the environmental variable was set by typing

(gdb) shell echo $MY_VAR

and it was blank. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Basically to set the environment variable in the command prompt, you can use the `set environment varname [=value]`. More information is present [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Environment.html#Environment). Since you have noted down there are huge number of paths to be set, you can add them to a file like `myGdbSrc` and then load them explicitly using `source [-s] [-v] filename`. You can find details on loading a file [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html).

I have tried both of them and it works.
HTH.

---

PS: I have tried it on GNU GDB 6.6 version on SUSE Linux. However, it must work across all version since it seems to be basic command.

Comment: Is there a way to execute a bash file, or am I limited to python?

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a wrapper script which sources your settings *before* loading gdb?

E.g. some trivial example:

```
#!/bin/sh

source my-script-which-sets-up-the-environment
gdb $*
```

This can of course also add arguments to the gdb invocation to setup paths, load a gdb script, etc.