# GDB autodisplay expression removed after make

Tags: debugging, gdb, disp

I am debugging a c program.
There is one breakpoint inside a function and I created some auto-display expressions for further stepping ( e.g. '(gdb) display *array@30').

Every time I issue a make and then run the application again, these auto-displays are removed. I checked via info display, they aren't disabled, they are gone. However, they seem to get removed on the run, after make they are still there.

Is there something to save and restore them, or simply keep them in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a auto-loaded commands for every run of the GDB, then you can use the loading scripts. Here (inside the script) you can customize the command. You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241972/source-a-script-from-gdb/13244207#13244207) for details.